# Does Rails have a way to handle has_one join tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Consider the following model setup:

```
Model A
  has one B1, type: B
  has one B2, type: B

Model B
  has many A
```

I want to be able have this work:

```
class Motorcycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :front_tire, class_name: "Tire"
  has_one :back_tire, class_name: "Tire"
end

class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :motorcycles
end
```

The end result would be me being able to do this:

```
m = Motorcycle.new
ft = Tire.new
bt = Tire.new
m.front_tire = ft
m.back_tire = bt
m.save
Tire.first.motorcycles #=> [...]
```

Comment: Pair `has_one` against `belongs_to`, always.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `has_many` paired with `has_one`, `has_*` needs to be paired with `belongs_to` (of course with exception of `has_many :through`).

So, you need to either change to `motorcycle` `belongs_to` :`front_tire` or create a third join model.

Comment: Changing belongs_to would mean I can't use `ft.motorcycles` which fails the requirement.

Comment: A join table means I can't have the position attribute.

Comment: of course you can have a position attribute with join model (join *model* to use with has_many :through, e.g. TireInstallation, not join table for habtm). that's what the join models are for.

Comment: I mean that you can't reference the join table's columns in the conditions option of has_*. I think the solution here is a join model, like you're now suggesting. I think I just skipped over that open.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for basic [Single-table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance), as front tires and back tires really aren't the same thing, but rather specific types of tires. To facilitate this, you would need to add a `type` string column to your `tires` table, and declare two sub-classes of the `Tire` class:

```
class Motorcycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :front_tire
  belongs_to :back_tire
end

class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class FrontTire < Tire
  has_many :motorcycles
end

class BackTire < Tire
  has_many :motorcycles
end
```

This would allow you to use `Tire.first`, which would return either an instance of `FrontTire` or `BackTire`, which would have many `motorcycles`. This fulfills your `Tire.first.motorcycles` requirement.

```
m = Motorcycle.new
ft = FrontTire.new # id 1
bt = BackTire.new  # id 2
m.front_tire = ft
m.back_tire = bt
m.save
Tire.first.motorcycles # returns FrontTire #1

# Or, find specifically by tire type
FrontTire.first.motorcycles # all motorcycles with this front-tire
BackTire.first.motorcycles  # all motorcycles with this back-tire
```

Alternatively, you could simply use a generic `tires` relationship, now that front and back tires are different classes:

```
class Motorcycle
  has_many :tires
end

class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class FrontTire < Tire
  has_many :motorcycles, foreign_key: :tire_id
end

class BackTire < Tire
  has_many :motorcycles, foreign_key: :tire_id
end
```

Npw `Motorcycle.first.tires` would return an array of two objects, one instance of a `FrontTire` and one instance of a `BackTire`. You would likely want to add a validator to prevent multiple front/back tires being assigned to the same motorcycle.

Comment: This is more on the right track, but I disagree with the relationship.  The simple english tells the story:  A tire belongs_to an motorcycle.   A motorcycle has_one :front_tire and has_one :back_tire.  It simply sounds wrong to say that a tire has_many motorcycles.

Comment: The simple English isn't really relevant in this case. The foreign key belongs in Motorcycle: A Motorcycle needs to know what kind of front-tire is uses, and which kind of back-tire it uses. The fact that Rails has only one way of expression this relationship ("belongs to") is a failing in the way Rails tries to boil down many types of database relatonship to a single English-language concept. The database implementation is correct; that Rails can't adequately express it doesn't mean you should use an *incorrect* database implementation.

Comment: And it might help to clarify that we're not talking about specific physical instances of this motorcycle "belongs to" this particualr piece-of-round-rubber. We're saying that "A Dunlop part #12345 Front Tire is used by *these* models of motorcycles" and "This 2012 Kawasaki motorcycle uses a Dunlop part #54321 rear tire". The fact that Rails needs to boil down this mutual-ownership to a belongs_to/has_many is simply Rails failing to provide the English-language equivalent for this particular relationship.

Comment: I guess the point being that I've just convinced myself that this should be a mutual has-and-belongs-to-many relationship with a joining table between motorcycles and tires; A specific type of tire can belong to many motorcycles and visa-versa.

Comment: Ok, I guess I would have named it TireModel or TireType or something.  Yes, if if the tire is a type that can be on many motorcycles, it looks like you need a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested at all but how about something like this:

```
has_many :motorcycles,
         :class_name => 'Motorcycle',
         :finder_sql => proc { "select * from motorcycles
                         where front_tire_id = #{id} OR
                         back_tire_id = #{id}" }
```

Comment: That handles only one side, and not the other. I'd also like Rails to elagantly handle it. Seems like this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work

```
class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :motorcycle
end
```

change the `has_many :motercycles` to `belongs_to :motorcycle`

`Motorcycle` has many tires (through `has_one`)
`Tires` belong to `motorcycle`

or you could have used something like

```
class Motorcycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tires
end

class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :motorcycle
end
```

with `Tire` containing a `column position` wich may hold values for front or back

you could create some constants in model to maintain those like

```
class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
 FROUT 1
 BACK 2
 #....
end
```

This is just an another option :)

Comment: This fails as I can't do `ft.motorcycles`.

Comment: it will be `ft.motorcycle` as it is has one

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it with this set of code:

```
class Motorcycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tire_brands
  has_one :front_tire, class_name: "Tire"
  has_one :back_tire, class_name: "Tire"
end

class Tire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :motorcycle
  belongs_to :tire_brand
end

class TireBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tires
  has_many :motorcycles, through: :tires
end
```

Comment: Bad design. You should have gone for the HABTM as meagar suggested.